# how to drop duplicates in pandas when entries are sets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hash, set, series

I have a series whose entries are sets. I want to remove all duplicate entries, using [`pandas.Series.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) but get an error. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series([{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {4,5,6}])
ser.drop_duplicates()
```

The last line gives the following exception:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Whereas I would like to get:

```
0    {1, 2, 3}
1    {4, 5, 6}
```

Is this a bug? Or is there another way to acheive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us using `astype(str)` then `duplicated`

```
ser[~ser.astype(str).duplicated(keep='first')]
Out[170]: 
0    {1, 2, 3}
1    {4, 5, 6}
dtype: object
```

More Info :

```
ser.astype(str).duplicated(keep='first')
Out[171]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```